# Are Spring AOP proxy classes removed by Garbage collector?

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

If my project has multiple pointcuts defined for 25 different classes. Suppose a request is processed using all these classes. So as per Spring AOP, proxies will be created for all 25 classes.

Since these proxies are stored in memory. If huge number of requests are using the service simultaneously so will there be any memory wastage issue? Are such proxy classes regularly deleted by garbage collector in between or they still remain in the memory?

Comment: Assuming those are services they aren't as there is only a single instance of the service so why should it get GC'ed.

Comment: It would be better if you would describe your real problem. Do you have any such problem and reason to think that it is due to Spring proxies? If so, describe it and also ideally show code reproducing your problem, or at least explain the situation as well as possible.